# Drag and drop file example in pygobject

Tags: python, pygtk, pygobject

I am trying to port sample drag and drop example from pygtk FAQ to pygobject.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
import urllib
import os

TARGET_TYPE_URI_LIST = 80
dnd_list = [ ( 'text/uri-list', 0, TARGET_TYPE_URI_LIST ) ]

def get_file_path_from_dnd_dropped_uri(uri):
    # get the path to file
    path = ""
    if uri.startswith('file:\\\\\\'): # windows
        path = uri[8:] # 8 is len('file:///')
    elif uri.startswith('file://'): # nautilus, rox
        path = uri[7:] # 7 is len('file://')
    elif uri.startswith('file:'): # xffm
        path = uri[5:] # 5 is len('file:')

    path = urllib.url2pathname(path) # escape special chars
    path = path.strip('\r\n\x00') # remove \r\n and NULL

    return path

def on_drag_data_received(widget, context, x, y, selection, target_type, timestamp):
    if target_type == TARGET_TYPE_URI_LIST:
        uri = selection.data.strip('\r\n\x00')
        print 'uri', uri
        uri_splitted = uri.split() # we may have more than one file dropped
        for uri in uri_splitted:
            path = get_file_path_from_dnd_dropped_uri(uri)
            print 'path to open', path
            if os.path.isfile(path): # is it file?
                data = file(path).read()
                #print data

w = gtk.Window()
w.connect('drag_data_received', on_drag_data_received)
w.drag_dest_set( gtk.DEST_DEFAULT_MOTION |
              gtk.DEST_DEFAULT_HIGHLIGHT | gtk.DEST_DEFAULT_DROP,
              dnd_list, gtk.gdk.ACTION_COPY)

w.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Can someone please help me to make drag and drop example work on pygobject. I am on windows7.

Comment: Is it `python2` or `python3` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working example for drag and drop using pygobject (Tested on Windows7)

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf, Gdk
import urllib
import os
TARGET_TYPE_URI_LIST = 80

def get_file_path_from_dnd_dropped_uri(uri):
    # get the path to file
    path = ""
    if uri.startswith('file:\\\\\\'): # windows
        path = uri[8:] # 8 is len('file:///')
    elif uri.startswith('file://'): # nautilus, rox
        path = uri[7:] # 7 is len('file://')
    elif uri.startswith('file:'): # xffm
        path = uri[5:] # 5 is len('file:')

    path = urllib.url2pathname(path) # escape special chars
    path = path.strip('\r\n\x00') # remove \r\n and NULL

    return path

def on_drag_data_received(widget, context, x, y, selection, target_type, timestamp):
    if target_type == TARGET_TYPE_URI_LIST:
        uri = selection.get_data().strip('\r\n\x00')
        print 'uri', uri
        uri_splitted = uri.split() # we may have more than one file dropped
        for uri in uri_splitted:
            path = get_file_path_from_dnd_dropped_uri(uri)
            print 'path to open', path
            if os.path.isfile(path): # is it file?
                data = file(path).read()
                #print data

w = Gtk.Window()
w.connect('drag_data_received', on_drag_data_received)

w.drag_dest_set( Gtk.DestDefaults.MOTION|
                  Gtk.DestDefaults.HIGHLIGHT | Gtk.DestDefaults.DROP,
                  [Gtk.TargetEntry.new("text/uri-list", 0, 80)], Gdk.DragAction.COPY)



w.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```